# AADB2C : Reset active directory Member Password functionality

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to update azure active directory members passwords.
I have tried with both Microsoft graph api and azure ad graph api.
However I am not able to update members password.
I have tried with all the permission.
Please refer below error:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to find out the solution?

Comment: It needs pretty heavy permissions AFAIK. If an app needs to be able to do it by itself, it needs higher permissions than what you can give in the portal. You would need to assign a high admin role to the service principal with e.g. powershell.

Comment: But if you have an admin logged in to your app and you are doing it in a delegated way, it is possible to do with "regular" permissions.

Comment: Actually I am a guest user in this active directory B2C. I do not have admin user credentials. Could you please tell me in brief how we can assign permission using powershell?

Comment: Hi @juunas - Could you please help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: @ Wayne Yang, I have given these permission which you suggested me. However still not able to update password.

Comment: @PankajDhote . Well, I will do a further test and keep you updated.

Comment: @ Wayne Yang, Thank You for your help.

Comment: Hi, @PankajDhote , I have updated my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have enough privileges to reset users password, you need to assign `Company Administrators` Role to your Service principal. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0) to do that.

1. Use AAD Powershell to Connect AAD:

`Connect-AzureAD`

2. Get the Role of Company Administrator:

`$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Company Administrator'}`

3. Assign the role to your SP:

`Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId $yoursp.ObjectId`

5. Get a new access token and  Rest the User Password in postman:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Wayne Yang - You are great! Yes, Now I am able to update member password. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @PankajDhote . I'm glad to hear that this answer is helpful.;-)